# How to put small numbers outside the pie slices without making a mess

Tags: pgf-pie

I'm new to LaTeX and need some help with my figures.
I would like to to put small numbers outside the pie slices without making a mess. Having found this thread [Align 3 graph pies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321047/align-3-graph-pies), I tried it out, but didn't get all the way through with it. Right now, my pie looks like this:

[image: Pies]

I used the following code:

```
\usepackage{tikz,stackengine}
\makeatletter

\tikzstyle{chart}=
[legend label/.style={font={\scriptsize},anchor=west,align=left},
legend box/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size=5pt},
axis/.style={black,thin,->},
axis label/.style={anchor=east,font={\tiny}}]

\tikzstyle{bar chart}=[
chart, bar width/.code={
    \pgfmathparse{##1/2}
    \global\let\bar@w\pgfmathresult},
bar/.style={thin, draw=black},
bar label/.style={font={\bf\small},anchor=north},
bar value/.style={font={\footnotesize}},
bar width=.75,]

\tikzstyle{pie chart}=
[chart,
slice/.style={line cap=round, line join=round, thin, draw=black},
pie title/.style={font={}},
slice type/.style 2 args={
    ##1/.style={fill=##2},
    values of ##1/.style={}}]

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\newcommand{\pye}[3][]{
    \begin{scope}[#1]
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\curA}{90}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1}
        \def\c{(0,0)}
        \node[pie title] at (270:1.3) {#2};
        \foreach \v/\s in{#3}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\deltaA}{\v/100*360}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\nextA}{\curA + \deltaA}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\midA}{(\curA+\nextA)/2}
            \path[slice,\s] \c
            -- +(\curA:\r)
            arc (\curA:\nextA:\r)
            -- cycle;
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{max((\deltaA * -(.5/50) + 1) , .5)}
%%%            

%\pgfmathprintnumberto{#3}{\fnum} 
%\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{#3 pt < 10pt}}
%{\path (O) -- ++ (\midangle:\radius)
%node[inner sep=0,align=left,anchor=west,rotate=\midangle](nums#3)    {~~\fnum};}
%{\path (O) -- ++(\midangle:\innerpos) 
%node {\scalefont{#3}\beforenumber\fnum\afternumber};}         

%%%            
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
                \path \c -- node[pos=\d,pie values,values of \s]{$\v\%$} +    (\midA:\r);
            \end{pgfonlayer}
            \global\let\curA\nextA}
    \end{scope}}

\newcommand{\legend}[2][]{
    \begin{scope}[#1]
        \path
        \foreach \n/\s in {#2}
        {++(0,-5pt) node[\s,legend box] {} +(2pt,0) node[legend label]     {\n}};
    \end{scope}}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{center}

    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[pie chart,
slice type={A}{black!0},
slice type={B}{black!10},
slice type={C}{black!20},
slice type={D}{black!30},
slice type={E}{black!40},
slice type={F}{black!50},
slice type={G}{black!60},
slice type={H}{black!70},
pie values/.style={font={\small}},
scale=2]

\pye{1994}{6.1/A, 2.9/B, 0.2/C, 54.3/D, 25.2/E, 1.4/F, 6.7/G, 3.2/H}
\pye[xshift=2.2cm,values of coltello/.style={pos=1.1}]%
{2005}{6.8/A, 3.0/B, 0.5/C, 52.3/D, 25.6/E, 1.8/F, 7.1/G, 2.8/H}
\pye[xshift=4.4cm,values of caffe/.style={pos=1.1}]%
{2015}{7.2/A, 3.1/B, 0.6/C, 50.6/D, 26.5/E, 2.3/F, 7.5/G, 2.2/H}

\legend[shift={(0cm,-1.5cm)}]{{A}/A, {B}/B} 
\legend[shift={(1.4cm,-1.5cm)}]{{C}/C, {D}/D} 
\legend[shift={(2.8cm,-1.5cm)}]{{E}/E, {F}/F}
\legend[shift={(4.2cm,-1.5cm)}]{{G}/G, {H}/H}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This looks quite the way I want it to, only the small numbers should be placed outside the pies.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you want to auto-detect when a slice is too small, or can you select those slices manually (which would be much easier to implement)?

Comment: Manual selection would be enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this code already has a variable positioning algorithm.  I just boosted it a bit with a max of 1.2 radii.  Bigger than that makes it hard to associate numbers with slices.  Nothing can guarantee that numbers won't overlap, but it would help to alternate big and little slices.

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,stackengine}
\makeatletter

\tikzstyle{chart}=
[legend label/.style={font={\scriptsize},anchor=west,align=left},
legend box/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size=5pt},
axis/.style={black,thin,->},
axis label/.style={anchor=east,font={\tiny}}]

\tikzstyle{bar chart}=[
chart, bar width/.code={
    \pgfmathparse{##1/2}
    \global\let\bar@w\pgfmathresult},
bar/.style={thin, draw=black},
bar label/.style={font={\bf\small},anchor=north},
bar value/.style={font={\footnotesize}},
bar width=.75,]

\tikzstyle{pie chart}=
[chart,
slice/.style={line cap=round, line join=round, thin, draw=black},
pie title/.style={font={}},
slice type/.style 2 args={
    ##1/.style={fill=##2},
    values of ##1/.style={}}]

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\newcommand{\tempsum}{0}% reserve global name

\newcommand{\pye}[3][]{% #1=scope options, #2=title, #3=list of percent/legend
    \begin{scope}[#1]
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\curA}{90}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1}
        \def\c{(0,0)}
        \node[pie title] at (270:1.3) {#2};
        \def\tempsum{0}
        \foreach \v/\s in{#3}{
          \pgfmathparse{\v+\tempsum}
          \global\let\tempsum=\pgfmathresult}
        \foreach \v/\s in{#3}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\deltaA}{\v/\tempsum*360}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\nextA}{\curA + \deltaA}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\midA}{(\curA+\nextA)/2}
            \path[slice,\s] \c
            -- +(\curA:\r)
            arc (\curA:\nextA:\r)
            -- cycle;
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{min(1.2,max((1.5-0.1*\v) , .5)}

%%%            

%\pgfmathprintnumberto{#3}{\fnum} 
%\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{#3 pt < 10pt}}
%{\path (O) -- ++ (\midangle:\radius)
%node[inner sep=0,align=left,anchor=west,rotate=\midangle](nums#3)    {~~\fnum};}
%{\path (O) -- ++(\midangle:\innerpos) 
%node {\scalefont{#3}\beforenumber\fnum\afternumber};}         

%%%            
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
                \path \c -- node[pos=\d,pie values,values of \s]{$\v\%$} +  (\midA:\r);
            \end{pgfonlayer}
            \global\let\curA\nextA}
    \end{scope}}

\newcommand{\legend}[2][]{
    \begin{scope}[#1]
        \path
        \foreach \n/\s in {#2}
        {++(0,-5pt) node[\s,legend box] {} +(2pt,0) node[legend label]     {\n}};
    \end{scope}}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[pie chart,
slice type={A}{black!0},
slice type={B}{black!10},
slice type={C}{black!20},
slice type={D}{black!30},
slice type={E}{black!40},
slice type={F}{black!50},
slice type={G}{black!60},
slice type={H}{black!70},
pie values/.style={font={\small}},
scale=2]

\pye{1994}{6.1/A, 2.9/B, 0.2/C, 54.3/D, 25.2/E, 1.4/F, 6.7/G, 3.2/H}
\pye[xshift=2.2cm,values of coltello/.style={pos=1.1}]%
{2005}{6.8/A, 3.0/B, 0.5/C, 52.3/D, 25.6/E, 1.8/F, 7.1/G, 2.8/H}
\pye[xshift=4.4cm,values of caffe/.style={pos=1.1}]%
{2015}{7.2/A, 3.1/B, 0.6/C, 50.6/D, 26.5/E, 2.3/F, 7.5/G, 2.2/H}

\legend[shift={(0cm,-1.5cm)}]{{A}/A, {B}/B} 
\legend[shift={(1.4cm,-1.5cm)}]{{C}/C, {D}/D} 
\legend[shift={(2.8cm,-1.5cm)}]{{E}/E, {F}/F}
\legend[shift={(4.2cm,-1.5cm)}]{{G}/G, {H}/H}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you understand the syntax, do you know how I can get the pie to be full, even though the percentages might not add up to 100 due to rounding errors? In the above example it is okay, but I have other pies where the sum is only 99.9 and the pie doesn't look good.

Comment: Doesn't work, I have both too small and too high sums in various pies :(

Comment: I added a loop to sum the \v and use that to scale the angles.  You realize that the \v don't have to be percents any more.

Answer (score 1):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

A command `\WCtest` is defined of which the output depends on whether the percentage is larger than 6. This command is used in the keys `data` and `wheel data`. Here, the percentage is obtained with `\WCperc`.

The shades of black are obtained with `black!\fpeval{10*(\WCcount-1)}` in the key `slices style`. Here `\WCcount` gives the current number of the slice.

The first `\wheelchart` is positioned with the key `at={(-6.5,0)}`. The second is positioned at the initial coordinate `(0,0)` and the third uses the key `at={(6.5,0)}`.

The legend is placed in a separate `\wheelchart`. Here we set the keys `data=`, `slices style={fill=none}` and `wheel data={}` so that no slices are drawn and no data or wheel data are placed.

The legend is determined by the key `legend`. This is a `tabular` which is placed in a `\node`. The rows are determined by the key `legend row`. The result of all rows can be obtained with `\WClegend`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\WCtest#1#2{%
  \pgfmathparse{\WCpercentage>6?"#1":"#2"}%
  \pgfmathresult%
}
\pgfkeys{
  /wheelchart,
  anchor xsep=32,
  counterclockwise,
  data=\WCtest{}{\WCperc},
  perc precision=1,
  pie,
  slices style={
    black!\fpeval{10*(\WCcount-1)},
    draw=black,
    line join=bevel
  },
  WClistdata={A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H},
  wheel data=\WCtest{\WCperc}{},
  wheel data pos=0.8
}
\wheelchart[
  at={(-6.5,0)},
  caption=1994
]{6.1,2.9,0.2,54.3,25.2,1.4,6.7,3.2}
\wheelchart[
  caption=2005
]{6.8,3.0,0.5,52.3,25.6,1.8,7.1,2.8}
\wheelchart[
  at={(6.5,0)},
  caption=2015
]{7.2,3.1,0.6,50.6,26.5,2.3,7.5,2.2}
\wheelchart[
  data=,
  legend columns=4,
  legend row={\tikz\fill[black!\fpeval{10*(\WCcount-1)},draw=black] (0,0) rectangle (0.3,0.3); & \WClistdata},
  legend={
    \node[anchor=north] at (0,-4.5) {%
      \begin{tabular}{*{4}{l@{ }p{2.5cm}}}%
      \WClegend%
      \end{tabular}%
    };
  },
  slices style={fill=none},
  total count=8,
  wheel data={}
]{}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```