# Reading quoted csv

Tags: pgfplotstable, csv

I would like to read in data from a CSV file into a plot. Unfortunately, the data contains commas itself:

```
Name, Description, Data
hello, "hello, world", 1
```

Note that the data is quoted using quotation marks, which is quite common when it comes to CSV files. I read in the file using the following:

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\datatable}
```

Problem is: the `pgfplotstable` package does not seem to be able to handle quotes, specifically, I get an error message because there are apparently too many entries in the second row. I edited the file in the following way:

```
Name, Description, Data
hello, hello\, world, 1
```

This seems to work OK. I then tried to use the `Description` column as symbolic coordinates in a plot:

```
  \begin{axis}[yticklabels from table={\datatable}{Description}]
  # ....
  \end{axis}
```

Problem in this case: the commas disappear, the label only reads "hello  world".

Is there a way to read the quoted entries (I am stuck using `pgfplotstable`), or to quote the file in such a way that I can read the column into the labels?

Comment: Providing an MWE would help.  LaTeX understands *groups*, rather than *quotes*.  So maybe `hello, {hello, world}, 1` would work.  Note that `\,` is a LaTeX macro for a small horizontal space, not a quoted comma, which would explain why your test did not produce a comma.

Comment: I tested my theory on another question's `pgfplotstable`. at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375737/tikz-wheelchart-prevent-labels-from-overlapping/378458#378458, changing `"Grapes",   22` to `"{Grapes, red}",   22` and it works fine with the grouped comma.  Without the grouping braces, it errs just as in your case.

Comment: If you can manually place braces then that's the easiest solution.

Comment: Another way is to define, let's say, `\let\comma,` and then in your data set use `hello, hello\comma{} world, 1`, but this seems more difficult than the group approach.  Note though, that with the group approach, even `hello, hello{,} world, 1` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments: since I am able to modify the CSV directly, an acceptable way to escape commas is be the fifth option, i.e. surrounding the cell by curly braces:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Name,Description,Data
hello,hello,1
second,second \, option,2
third,third \, option,3
fourth,"{fourth, option}",4
fifth,{fifth, option},5
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}\datatable

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ymin=-5,ymax=5,yticklabels from table={\datatable}{Description}]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Just as a note: I used the `\,` not to produce extra spacing but to escape the comma. After all, a line of the form `first, "first, option", 1` will cause latex to fail with the error message

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Table 'data.csv' appears to have too many columns
```

So the parsing options for CSV files using `pgfplotstable` seem to be rather limited...