# Two wheelcharts next to each other

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage, alignment

I'm having trouble placing two wheelcharts next to each other. I have combined answers to [Two figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side) and [Tikz Wheelchart - Prevent labels from overlapping](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375737/tikz-wheelchart-prevent-labels-from-overlapping) to make two wheelcharts side by side. I have the following problems:

**1. The plots are not vertically aligned (one wheel is lower than the other and one label is way lower than the other):**
[image]

**2. I would like the right graph to read 521.6 MWp instead of 'installations'**

My code for the MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[inner = 25mm, outer = 25mm,  top = 30mm, bottom = 20mm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{installations.csv}
Name,   Quantity
"Japan", 66
"China", 12
"Korea", 8
"Other", 23 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{installedcapacity.csv}
Name,   Quantity
"Japan", 95.516
"China", 394.258
"Korea", 16.901
"Other", 14.589 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[ignore chars=",col sep=comma]{installations.csv}\datainstallations
\pgfplotstableread[ignore chars=",col sep=comma]{installedcapacity.csv}\datacapacity

\pgfplotstableread{
    clr
    blue!70!black!70
    red!70!black
    black!70!white
    white!70!black
    pink!30!red!60!
    purple!80
    green!60!black!40!
    black!50
    pink!30!red!60!
    blue!70
    green!10!orange!90!
    yellow!50!orange!50!
    pink!30!red!60!
}\MyColors

% Adjusts the size of the wheel:
\def\innerradius{1.6cm}
\def\outerradius{2cm}

\newcommand\LabelName{}
\newcommand\LabelValue{}

% The main macro
\newcommand{\wheelchart}[1]{
    % Calculate total
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\totalnum}{0}
    % get number of rows in table
    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{#1}
    % minus 1 because indexing starts as zero
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\RowsInTable}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\RowsInTable} {
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{Quantity}\of{#1}
        \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotsretval+\totalnum}
        \global\let\totalnum=\pgfmathresult
    }
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        % The text in the center of the wheel
        \node[align=center,text width=2*\innerradius]{\pgfmathprintnumber{\totalnum}~Installations};
        % Calculate the thickness and the middle line of the wheel
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelwidth}{\outerradius-\innerradius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{(\outerradius+\innerradius)/2}

        % Rotate so we start from the top
        \begin{scope}[rotate=90]

        % Loop through each value set. \cumnum keeps track of where we are in the wheel
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cumnum}{0}


        \foreach \i in {0,...,\RowsInTable} {
            % get values from table
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{Name}\of{#1}\global\let\LabelName=\pgfplotsretval
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{Quantity}\of{#1}\renewcommand\LabelValue{\pgfplotsretval}

            \pgfmathsetmacro{\newcumnum}{\cumnum + \LabelValue/\totalnum*360}


            % Calculate the percent value
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\percentage}{\LabelValue}
            % Calculate the mid angle of the colour segments to place the labels
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\midangle}{-(\cumnum+\newcumnum)/2}


            % This is necessary for the labels to align nicely
            \pgfmathparse{
                (-\midangle<180?"west":"east")
            } \edef\textanchor{\pgfmathresult}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\labelshiftdir{ifthenelse(\RowsInTable==0,-1,1)*(1-2*(-\midangle>180))}

            % Draw the color segments. Somehow, the \midrow units got lost, so we add 'pt' at the end. Not nice...
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{clr}\of{\MyColors}
            \fill[color=\pgfplotsretval] (-\cumnum:\outerradius) arc (-\cumnum:-(\newcumnum):\outerradius) --
            (-\newcumnum:\innerradius) arc (-\newcumnum:-(\cumnum):\innerradius) -- cycle;

            % Draw the data labels
            \pgfmathsetmacro\labelmag{
                1 + .9*(abs(1/sin(\midangle)))^1 - .03*(abs(1/sin(\midangle)))^2}
            \draw  [*-,thin] node [append after command={(\midangle:\midradius pt) -- 
                (\midangle:\outerradius + \labelmag ex) -- (\tikzlastnode)}] at
            (\midangle:\outerradius + \labelmag ex) 
            [xshift=\labelshiftdir*0.5cm,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, ,anchor=\textanchor]{\LabelName: \pgfmathprintnumber{\percentage}};

            % Set the old cumulated angle to the new value
            \global\let\cumnum=\newcumnum
        }

        \end{scope}
        %      \draw[gray] (0,0) circle (\outerradius) circle (\innerradius);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \wheelchart{\datainstallations}
    \caption{first figure}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \wheelchart{\datacapacity}
    \caption{second figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with the following changes (in code indicated by `% <---` ) in the your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[inner = 25mm, outer = 25mm,  top = 30mm, bottom = 20mm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{installations.csv}
Name,   Quantity
"Japan", 66
"China", 12
"Korea", 8
"Other", 23
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{installedcapacity.csv}
Name,   Quantity
"Japan", 95.516
"China", 394.258
"Korea", 16.901
"Other", 14.589
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[ignore chars=",col sep=comma]{installations.csv}\datainstallations
\pgfplotstableread[ignore chars=",col sep=comma]{installedcapacity.csv}\datacapacity

\pgfplotstableread{
    clr
    blue!70!black!70
    red!70!black
    black!70!white
    white!70!black
    pink!30!red!60!
    purple!80
    green!60!black!40!
    black!50
    pink!30!red!60!
    blue!70
    green!10!orange!90!
    yellow!50!orange!50!
    pink!30!red!60!
}\MyColors

% Adjusts the size of the wheel:
\def\innerradius{1.6cm}
\def\outerradius{2cm}

\newcommand\LabelName{}
\newcommand\LabelValue{}

% The main macro
\newcommand{\wheelchart}[2]{ % <--- (from 1 to 2)
    % Calculate total
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\totalnum}{0}
    % get number of rows in table
    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{#1}
    % minus 1 because indexing starts as zero
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\RowsInTable}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\RowsInTable} {
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{Quantity}\of{#1}
        \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotsretval+\totalnum}
        \global\let\totalnum=\pgfmathresult
    }
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        % The text in the center of the wheel
        \node[align=center,text width=2*\innerradius]{\pgfmathprintnumber{\totalnum}~{#2}}; % <--- (name is now defined by second option of the command \wheelchart
        % Calculate the thickness and the middle line of the wheel
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\wheelwidth}{\outerradius-\innerradius}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{(\outerradius+\innerradius)/2}

        % Rotate so we start from the top
        \begin{scope}[rotate=90]
        % Loop through each value set. \cumnum keeps track of where we are in the wheel
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cumnum}{0}
        \foreach \i in {0,...,\RowsInTable} {
            % get values from table
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{Name}\of{#1}\global\let\LabelName=\pgfplotsretval
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{Quantity}\of{#1}\renewcommand\LabelValue{\pgfplotsretval}

            \pgfmathsetmacro{\newcumnum}{\cumnum + \LabelValue/\totalnum*360}

            % Calculate the percent value
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\percentage}{\LabelValue}
            % Calculate the mid angle of the colour segments to place the labels
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\midangle}{-(\cumnum+\newcumnum)/2}

            % This is necessary for the labels to align nicely
            \pgfmathparse{
                (-\midangle<180?"west":"east")
            } \edef\textanchor{\pgfmathresult}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\labelshiftdir{ifthenelse(\RowsInTable==0,-1,1)*(1-2*(-\midangle>180))}

            % Draw the color segments. Somehow, the \midrow units got lost, so we add 'pt' at the end. Not nice...
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{clr}\of{\MyColors}
            \fill[color=\pgfplotsretval] (-\cumnum:\outerradius) arc (-\cumnum:-(\newcumnum):\outerradius) --
            (-\newcumnum:\innerradius) arc (-\newcumnum:-(\cumnum):\innerradius) -- cycle;

            % Draw the data labels
            \pgfmathsetmacro\labelmag{
                1 + .9*(abs(1/sin(\midangle)))^1 - .03*(abs(1/sin(\midangle)))^2}
            \draw  [*-,thin] node [append after command={(\midangle:\midradius pt) --
                (\midangle:\outerradius + \labelmag ex) -- (\tikzlastnode)}] at
            (\midangle:\outerradius + \labelmag ex)
            [xshift=\labelshiftdir*0.5cm,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, ,anchor=\textanchor]{\LabelName: \pgfmathprintnumber{\percentage}};

            % Set the old cumulated angle to the new value
            \global\let\cumnum=\newcumnum
        }
        \end{scope}
        %      \draw[gray] (0,0) circle (\outerradius) circle (\innerradius);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \wheelchart{\datainstallations}{installation}\vskip\baselineskip % <--- added are name in wheel (installation) 
                                                                     % and vertical space for aligning wheels
    \caption{first figure}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \wheelchart{\datacapacity}{MWE} % <--- added are name in wheel (MWE)
    \caption{second figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]