# How to adjust the legend of a chart manually in wheelchart?

Tags: charts

How do I manually adjust/define the position of each legend when using the "wheelchart" package, I read somewhere that it is not possible to adjust in the "Wheelchart" package. The legends overlap when the value is low. Any idea or workaround is much appreciated.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart

[data=\WCvarC: \WCperc,
  lines=0.5,
  lines ext=0.5,
  lines sep=-0.2,
  lines style={
    postaction=decorate,
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position 0 with {
        \fill (0,0) circle[radius=0.1];
      }
    }
  },
  perc precision=1,
  radius={1.8}{2.2}
]

{
  55.55/green/Option A,
  6.55/red/Option B,
  29.59/blue/Option C,
  3.59/orange/Option D,
  4.73/purple/Option E
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be changed with the keys of the wheelchart package (which I wrote).

A solution similar to the one in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703206 can be used.

To adjust the length of the line in the fifth slice, the key `lines{5}=1` is used.

Also, the empty line between `\wheelchart` and the next `[` is removed. And also between the closing `]` and the next `{`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart[
  data=\WCvarC: \WCperc,
  lines=0.5,
  lines{5}=1,
  lines ext=0.5,
  lines sep=-0.2,
  lines style={
    postaction=decorate,
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position 0 with {
        \fill (0,0) circle[radius=0.1];
      }
    }
  },
  perc precision=1,
  radius={1.8}{2.2}
]{%
  55.55/green/Option A,
  6.55/red/Option B,
  29.59/blue/Option C,
  3.59/orange/Option D,
  4.73/purple/Option E%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for me `lines{5}=1,` is not working but i used this piece of your previous code: `lines={1/(0.5+abs(cos(\WCdataangle)))^1.1},`

Comment: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/wheelchart/slices style{list}'gnore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. }

Comment: @IamK The key `lines{5}=1` in the answer requires version 2.0 of the wheelchart package.

Comment: Thank you @matexmatics