# How can I make a pie chart which automatically changes 'inside' text to 'pin'

Tags: pgf-pie

How can I create a pie chart where if one of the labels doesn't fit, it will switch from having the text `inside` to being `pin`, or define it manually for each part, using pgf-pie, like this?

[image: a busy cat]

So far I only have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pie [rotate = 180,color={black!00},text=inside]
    {49/Drive Alone,
     15/Car Pool, 4/Bicycle,22/Walk,10/Walk}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338528/how-to-put-small-numbers-outside-the-pie-slices-without-making-a-mess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's going to take some hacking of the `pgf-pie` package itself to make this work. I put the edited version online here [modified version of pgf-pie.sty](https://pastebin.com/Au5Bd2Au)

You need to download it as `pgf-pie-hacked.sty` into a location that is found by LaTeX (for testing purposes, you can save it in the same folder as your LaTeX document). Use it with `\usepackage{pgf-pie-hacked}`.

The `\pie` macro - only for circular mode! I didn't touch the others - now expects an explicit specification for each slice, like so:

```
\usepackage{pgf-pie-hacked}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pie [rotate = 180,color={black!00}]
    {49/Drive Alone/inside, 15/Car Pool/inside, 4/Bicycle/pin, 22/Walk/inside, 10/Walk/inside}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As already remarked by @Michael, the pgf-pie package does not support this natively. Therefore, the only solution is to change the definitions in `pgf-pie.sty`.

I am proposing a different solution which is a little bit more "automatic".
The idea is to set a threshold on the angle, under which the text is put in a pin automatically.
The modified package is [in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/bordaigorl/e4e857cfd551352d58b79b8783cb5a6f).
Here's a demo, where all the slices narrower than 50 degrees (`outside under=50`) will have the text as pin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pie [rotate = 180,color={black!00},text=inside,outside under=50]
    {49/Drive Alone,
     15/Car Pool, 4/Bicycle,22/Walk,10/Walk}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the design of pgf-pie treats numbers and labels separately, so a non-hackish way to move the number with the text would require a bit of refactoring. To give a little more flexibility I added the `no number` style that removes the numbers altogether, so for example you can embed them in the labels manually. For added flexibility I define `\and` so that it is a linebreak when inside, just a space when outside. To force a linebreak use `\\` instead of `\and`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pie [rotate = 180,color={black!00},text=inside,outside under=50,no number]
    {49/Drive Alone\and49\%,
     15/Car Pool\and15\%, 4/Bicycle\and4\%,22/Walk\and22\%,10/Walk\and10\%}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Very good solution. You may want to submit your code to the package author and ask him to include it.

Comment: is there any way of getting this to work with recent versions of tikz-pie?

Answer (score 1):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

A command `\WCtest` is defined of which the output depends on whether the percentage is larger than 4. This command is used in the keys `data` and `wheel data`. Here, the percentage is obtained with `\WCperc`.

By using the key `lines={\WCpercentage>4?0:1}`, the length of the lines is 0 if the percentage is larger than 4 and 1 otherwise.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\WCtest#1#2{%
    \pgfmathparse{\WCpercentage>4?"#1":"#2"}%
    \pgfmathresult%
}
\wheelchart[
  data=\WCtest{}{\WCvarB{} \WCperc},
  lines={\WCpercentage>4?0:1},
  lines sep=-0.5,
  radius={0}{4},
  slices style={
    fill=none,
    draw=black,
    line join=bevel
  },
  wheel data=\WCtest{\WCvarB{} \WCperc}{}
]{%
  22/Walk,
  10/Bus,
  49/Drive Alone,
  15/Car Pool,
  4/Bicycle%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\def\printonly#1{\pgfmathparse{#1>3 ? "#1" : ""}\pgfmathresult}

\pie[
sum=auto,
before number=\printonly
] {11/A, 
4/\tikz[]{\draw[shorten <=-5mm, thin] (0:-1) -- +(33:5mm) node[]{tiny};},
79.9/C, 
10/D,
1/\tikz[]{
\draw[shorten <=-5mm, thin] (0:0) -- +(0:5mm) node[]{$1\%$ very tiny};
} }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```