# Hide some numbers - PGFpie

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

I am dealing with package pgf-pie to draw some pictures.

However, I would like to hide some percentages, that the smaller, because they don't fit in the sectors. I would just like to leave the ones with larger percentages.

See my figure.

[image]

The code is the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\pie[radius=4]
   {45/Palm.,
    25/SP,
    29/Cor.,
    1/San.}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

There is a possibility of hide all numbers, but I don't want, only the smallers. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 5):

This question is very similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/514816), one can more or less copy the answer.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\def\printonlylargeenough#1#2{\unless\ifdim#2pt<#1pt\relax
#2\printnumbertrue
\else
\printnumberfalse
\fi}
\newif\ifprintnumber
\pie[radius=4,before number=\printonlylargeenough{10},
    after number=\ifprintnumber\%\fi]
   {45/Palm.,
    25/SP,
    29/Cor.,
    1/San.}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This will only display percentages larger than 10%.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\pgfpie@ifnum[3]{%
  \ifnum\numexpr#1\relax#2\numexpr#3\relax
    \expandafter\pgfutil@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\pgfutil@secondoftwo
  \fi
}

\renewcommand\pgfpie@numbertext[1]{%
  \pgfpie@ifnum{#1}{>}{10}{%
    #1\%%
  }{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\pie[radius=4]
   {45/Palm.,
    25/SP,
    29/Cor.,
    1/San.}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```