# How can I center minipage text and adjust pgf-pie text

Tags: minipage, pgf-pie

I am using minipage to divide a figure into two positions, on the left I have a figure made with pgf-pie that I would like the large text to be able to write outside and in the case of the text I would like it to be in the center (for please see the image)

[image: example image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}

\section{example}

\hrule
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \caption{Example}\label{fig:ex1}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
            \pie[/tikz/nodes={text=white, font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
            text=inside,
            explode={0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1},color={blue!70,cyan!70,red!70,orange!50}]{9.3/Cedro\\rojo, 19.45/Café, 30.4/Cacao, 40.43/Tornillo }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}\hfill\vrule\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
        vallis augue. Etiam facilisis. Nunc elementum fermen-
        tum wisi. Aenean placerat. Ut imperdiet, enim sed
        gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pul-
        vinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin
        tempus nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus quis tortor vitae
        risus porta vehicula.
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

> remember to check the other answers on the forum and it appears to be unsupported. [forum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384460/how-can-i-make-a-pie-chart-which-automatically-changes-inside-text-to-pin)

Comment: To vertically centre the text, use `[c]` instead of `[b]` (or just remove the option)

Comment: Your code does not compile. There is a missing `}` after the section

Comment: Can you please not ask multiple unrelated questions in a single post?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz hello, thanks, It was on both minipages to make that change b by c

Comment: My main problem is now with pgf-pie, please I need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using the `[b]` option you force your minipages to be bottom aligned. If that's not what you want, don't use this option
- you could manually add the text outside of the pie chart using a normal tikz node

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}

\section{example}

\hrule
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \caption{Example}\label{fig:ex1}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
            \pie[/tikz/nodes={text=white, font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
            text=inside,
            explode={0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1},color={blue!70,cyan!70,red!70,orange!50}]{9.3/, 19.45/Café, 30.4/Cacao, 40.43/Tornillo }
            \node[align=center,font=\footnotesize] at (4.2,0.8) {Cedro\\rojo};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{minipage}\hfill\vrule\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        vallis augue. Etiam facilisis. Nunc elementum fermen-
        tum wisi. Aenean placerat. Ut imperdiet, enim sed
        gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pul-
        vinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor. Proin
        tempus nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus quis tortor vitae
        risus porta vehicula.
    \end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

[image]