# How to prevent overlapping labels in a pie chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie, overlap

I would like to know how to prevent the labels of a pie chart from overlapping and to have more control over their position?

I am using the `pgf-pie` package, I don't know if it is possible to easily modify the package to make this possible. If not, I'm also interested in a more "manual" solution without `pgf-pie` and using `tikz`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{pgf-pie}    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[rotate=90, text=pin, hide number, sum=auto]{
            1000/{\pgfmathprintnumber{1000.0}},
            300/{\pgfmathprintnumber{300}},
            250/{\pgfmathprintnumber{250}},
            100/{\pgfmathprintnumber{100}},
            31.1/{\pgfmathprintnumber{31.1}},
            25.5/{\pgfmathprintnumber{25.5}},
            21.2/{\pgfmathprintnumber{21.2}}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could rotate the labels in the direction of the direction of the bissectrix, for instance

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338528/how-to-put-small-numbers-outside-the-pie-slices-without-making-a-mess

Comment: @BLegrand I think this package is not so much flexible, that there is an elementary solution for changing the pin-lengths individually. Fear you need to draw the chart by you own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer below uses the [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote.

The anchor of the data is determined by the key `anchor xsep`.

The length of the lines is determined by the key `lines`. For the fourth and sixth slice, this length is defined separately with the key `lines{4,6}`.

In the key `slices style` we use `\WClistcolors` which refers to items in the list given to the key `WClistcolors`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart[
  anchor xsep=30,
  counterclockwise,
  data=\pgfmathprintnumber{\WCvarA},
  lines=0.5,
  lines{4,6}=1.3,
  pie,
  slices style={
    \WClistcolors,
    draw=black,
    line join=bevel
  },
  WClistcolors={blue!60,cyan!60,yellow!60,orange!60,red!60,blue!60!cyan!60,cyan!60!yellow!60,red!60!cyan!60,red!60!blue!60,orange!60!cyan!60}
]{1000,300,250,100,31.1,25.5,21.2}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```